# php_com_dotnet extension on GoDaddy?

Tags: php, com, plesk, ini

How do I add the php_com_dotnet.dll to the plesk webhost edition on godaddy? I was told by GoDaddy to modify the user.ini file that they provide in the httpdocs folder.  Adding the following did nothing whatsoever - by the way, how would I even figure out what the extension_dir would be set to in GoDaddy?:

```
**[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
;extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext" 
enable_dl = On
com.allow_dcom = 1
com.autoregister_typelib = 1
com.autoregister_verbose = 1
com.autoregister_casesensitive = 0**
```

Finally, if this com extension IS successfully installed by some miracle, how will I get my com object recognized by GoDaddy?  Since PHP is a server side application, I believe that the dll would have to be regasm'd on the GoDaddy server, is this not correct?  And if so, where on the server would I save the dll?  I am thinking GoDaddy might not even allow this on their server...